# When to use hasStableIds true for the recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am currently playing with the `hasStableIds` of recycler view and I have the following observations:

1) When the `hasStableIds = false`:

- Once the `notifyDataSetChanged()` called, it will make all views as dirty and recycle them again, due to which `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` will be called for each item.

2) When the `hasStableIds = true`:

- Once the `notifyDataSetChanged()` called, it will check for the ids and then decide whether to create a viewHolder for the recyclerView item. If the data set is not changed then it will only call `onBindViewHolder()` not `onCreateViewHolder()` again.

So as per the above behaviour, I am confused that whether we should always use our recyclerview with the `hasStableIds = true` so that it will avoid creating viewholders again? or is there any specific conditions in which we should use it?

Answer (score 1):

According to docs

`Enables adapter publishes a unique Id/value that can act as a key for the item at a given position in recyclerView.`

If that item is relocated in the data set, the ID returned for that item should be the same.
*this enables you to avoid sudden blink when adapter notify changes or perform any positional action*,

**caution!**, it's not advisable unless you know that your lists items/content will not change during updates.

[Android hasStableIds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#hasstableids)

Answer (score 0):

If you store in adapter's dataList some state to show in UI dynamically you should set `hasStableIds` to `true`. It helps you wnen your list will change, for example with filter.